# validationEngine not submitting form using onValidationComplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#bbSignup").validationEngine('attach', {
  onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
      if ( status == "true" ) {
$("#bbSignup").submit();
    $("#bbSignup").hide();
    $("#bbRegister").insertAfter("Form Submitted");
      } else {

      }
  }  
});
   });
```

Nothing happens if I fill out all of the forms and hit submit. Even pressing it multiple times does nothing. Any ideas?

**---EDIT---**

I changed it to this:

```
jQuery("#bbSignup").validationEngine('attach', {
onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
if ( status == "true" ) {
alert(" The status is " + status + " and will submit ");
} else {
alert(" The status is " + status + " and will not submit ");
}
}  
});
```

If nothing is filled out the else alert fires correctly. if Everything is filled out the alert says "The status is true and will not submit". So it's like the if status == true is never being called.. weird

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Any errors in the console? Put an alert inside the validation complete callback - does it fire? If not, one of your selectors is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but you're interrogating `status` as though it holds a string. Since you're testing for the strings `"true"` and `"false"`, though, it seems more likely it holds a boolean.

Try simply

```
if (status) { //test it against the boolean true, not string "true"
```

Comment: That worked for the validation, but the form isn't submitting. I tried to keep it as a submit button and i tried to just change it to a button and add $("#bbSignup").submit(); under the true section but neither are working. It does give the right alert now though

Comment: So we're getting somewhere... you might want to vote my answer up, then ;-) Can you create a JS Fiddle showing the current problem?

Comment: The reason is I have other things going on in the page that may be causing the issue

Comment: Actually it's not exactly working.. it submits the form but then these 2 errors come up preventing any other code from being processed:

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Comment: Ouch, no idea what that error is. Might need to Google/SO that one separately, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hmm, I put the form has been submitted message and hide form function before the submit call and that works :) Thanks for your help again and sorry I couldn't vote up!

Comment: I am seeing the same problem.  Everything works fine until the form is submitted and then jquery chokes in the `onValidationComplete` handler.

Answer (score 2):

If a function is assigned to onValidationComplete then this is executed *instead* of the form being submitted, so your description is exactly what jQuery-Validation-Engine is designed to do.

Until jQuery-Validation-Engine version 2.6.4 this was the only behavior, from this version on you can return true in onValidationComplete to tell the validation engine to continue submitting the form. The default behavior if the function has no return value is still to stop the submit.

See https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/pull/442 for the change to handle return values.

Answer (score 0):

**try this...**

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery("#formID").validationEngine('attach',{
     onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
      if (status == true){
       YourFunctionReload();
       // here :)
       return true;
      }}});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, hope it will work for you..

```
$('#formID').validationEngine('attach',{
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status){

        if (status == true){
            $("#formID").submit();
            return true;
        }

    }
});
```